# How to make mongoose schema dynamic, depending upon the value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose, dynamic-schema

I am new to mongoose and I have searched alot about it and was not able to find out the ans. Please help, thanks in advance.

```
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    rollno: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isVoter: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Can I have a schema which would be dependent on the value of **isVoter**. For example if value of **isVoter** is **false** then we should have schema like this :

```
const user = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    rollno: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        unique: true,

    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isVoter: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true
    },
    promises: [
        {
           type: String
        }
    ]
    , {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can defined if one variable is `required` or not based in another property in this way:

```js
promises: [
        {
           type: String,
           required: function(){
             return this.isVoter == false
           }
        }
    ]
```

So, `promises` will be required only if `isVoter` is false. Otherwise will not be required.

Comment: I dont want **promises** in the schema when **isVoter** is **true**. Your solution allows to add **promises** even if **isVoter** is **true**.

Comment: Set false insetad of true. Anyway, if it is not the desired behaviour try to explain better the problem.

Comment: actually I want that if a person is voter, which means **isVoter == true**, then he/she will not have made any promises that means no one **should be able to add promises** when he/she is a voter. But your solution suggests that inspite of **isVoter == true**, promises can still be added.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pre` hook in mongoose, check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre) and before saving, check the `isVoter` value, if you don't want to save promises, try `this.promises = undefined`

```
user.pre('save',  function(next) {
    if(this.isVoter== true){
       this.promises = undefined
    }
    else{
      this.promises = "hello"
      //do somethings
    }
   next();
});
```

and in the schema promises should be definded